# MySQL ORDER BY clause not behaving correctly

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a query in which I am sorting the data on date and time column. I have five records with same date and time. All the records are coming fine according to the sorting and primary key. But the last record I add jumps to top of the position. And I have no clue why is it happening.

My query is:

```
SELECT table1.* , table2.name AS name1, table2.date AS date1, 
       table2.start_time AS time1, table2.end_time AS time2
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN
     table2
     ON table2.id = table1.id1
WHERE table1.id2 = '604'
ORDER BY table1.date ASC, table1.start_time ASC
```

also the record screenshot is attached. The top record has the latest id but it is coming on top. All these records in the image has the same date and time.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure why you are confused.  If the `date` and `time` columns on the five rows all have the same value, then they can be returned in *any* order.

If you also want them ordered by the `id`, then include that in the `order by`:

```
ORDER BY table1.date ASC, table1.start_time ASC, table1.id
```

You seem to have some notion of a "stable" sort for `order by`.  A stable sort is one that keeps the original ordering of the data, for keys that have the same value.  However, that is simply not possible in SQL, because tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering without an `order by`.

Comment: I do not want to sort by ID. I just want to know why that record is coming on top of others. Also if I add "order by" by ID it will disturb other records in the database

Comment: @AleemAhmad . . . The ids are in arbitrary order for any set of equivalent key values.